# java.sql.sqlexception column not found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to find max no from tr_id (primary key) in transaction table. 
Here is the table and it's layout. 
[image]

[image]

Here is my cord.

```
             try {
                ResultSet rs = db.getData("SELECT MAX(tr_id) FROM transaction");
                ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                for (int index = 1; index <= meta.getColumnCount(); index++) {
                    System.out.println("Column " + index + " is named " +    meta.getColumnName(index));
                }
                if (rs.first()) {
                    int tr_id = rs.getInt("tr_id");
               }
```

I'm using JDBC connection. When I'm running this cord I'm getting this error.

```
        Column 1 is named MAX(tr_id)
        java.sql.SQLException: Column 'tr_id' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.findColumn(ResultSet.java:955)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getInt(ResultSet.java:2570)
    at Controler.InvoiceFinalising.saveInvoice(InvoiceFinalising.java:57)
  etc..
```

The thing is when I'm searching out as "tr_id" column name goes to Max(tr_id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the column name in your sql query is max(tr_id). You can write it as

```
ResultSet rs = db.getData("SELECT MAX(tr_id) as tr_id FROM transaction");
```

now you will be able to get it.

Comment: is that like this?   db.putData("INSERT INTO invoice (inid,itid, cuid, itname, qty, sprice, total, isdate, redate,tr_id)  VALUES ('" + txtInvoiceID.getText() + "','" + itemid + "', '" + txtCuID.getText() + "', '" + name + "','" + qty + "', '" + up + "', '" + total + "', '" + date1.trim() + "', '" + date2.trim() + "', '" + rs.getInt("tr_id") + "') "); now I'm getting tr_id not found error again. :(